# Converting HTML file into c# as string

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am looking for a way to design a simple HTML file, and in runtime - to load it as string to the c#.

I am trying to File.Open it, but it resides in a different location than the binary code.

is there a simple way to tell the build process to load it into a string?

thanks

Comment: Please provide your source code and indicate exactly what error you get and when.

Comment: Are you sure you want to treat it as a string?  What are you attempting to do with the HTML file?  It is very possible there is a specific class to help you accomplish your goal.  Give us some more info.
That said, you should be able to load the file from anywhere on the system, either with a fully qualified path or with a relative path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. I used RESOURCES to load a file, and it converted to be a string... :)

thanks all

Comment: Very bad answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ASP.NET, and the HTML file is relative to your website path:

```
string html = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/virtualPathTo/file.html"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is on another server, the easiest thing to do is use the HTTPWebRequest class to get the HTML.